# What dimension is the gradient vector output of tSNE

Tags: python, gradient-descent, dimensionality-reduction, tsne, vector-space

My question is this: Suppose we have   -dimensional vectors. We want to reduce the dimension to  2 using tSNE, naturally. When we compute tSNE using gradient descent, the gradient vector computed at each iteration contains exactly this many real numbers:

1. 
2. 
3. 2
4. 2

This question relies on how many dimensions tSNE's gradient vector is.

I'm between nd and 2n.  If the gradient vector output is in d dimension, meaning the original dimension of all the input points, then the answer is nd, as there would be d real numbers for each n.  However, if the gradient vector gets outputted in the 2nd dimension, then the answer is 2n, as there would be 2 real numbers for each n.

Comment: This is not the proper forum where to ask this question as there isn't any coding issue, but it's a more conceptual problem.